# How to sort a varchar column that contains numbers and letters in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `varchar` column that contain numbers `(1-99999)` and letters `(AM0001-BF9999).`

Since it has letters so i can't just convert it to `int`.

*Is there a way to maybe use `grouping_id` to sort this column by numbers (small to large) then follow by letters (alphabetically)?*

Thanks..

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! Why are you storing numbers as `varchar` ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to know what the maximum length of your field is. Assuming 25 characters for illustrative purposes, this will work:

```
select
    v
from (
    select 
        right(space(25) + v,25) as v
    from ( values
         ('1-99999')
        ,('AM0001-BF9999')
    ) data(v)
)data
order by v
```

to yield:

```
v
-------------------------
                  1-99999
            AM0001-BF9999
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `ISNUMERIC` function like this:

```
select * from test_table
order by 
     case isnumeric(test_column) 
     when 1 then convert(int,test_column)
     else 999999 end, test_column
```

### [Sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/61be3/7).

Comment: may I know the reason for putting `999999`?

Comment: @RanPaul any value equal or greater than `999999` will work. Because the maximum numeric value of the `test_column` is `999999`, so putting `999999` there will ensure that all the non-numeric values will be ordered after the numeric values. So you have 2 columns for ordering, their ordered (dash-separated) values may look like this: `[1, 1] - [2, 2] - ... - [999999, 999999] - [999999, AM0001] - [999999, AM0002] - [999999, AM0003] - ...` As you can see, starts from the non-numeric values, the first (computed value) is always `999999`

Answer (score 0):

That's what you get when you denormalize your database schema.
Prefix and number should be stored separately.
That said, this is what I did when I had the same problem:

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE
ORDER BY dbo.GetNumbers(YOUR_FIELD), YOUR_FIELD




Create Function dbo.GetNumbers(@Data VarChar(8000))
Returns int
AS
Begin   
    Return CAST(Left(
             SubString(@Data, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', @Data), 8000), 
             PatIndex('%[^0-9.-]%', SubString(@Data, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', @Data), 8000) + 'X')-1) AS int)
End
```

See also this post for extracting numbers from strings
http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/extracting-numbers-with-sql-server/